# Как сделать POST запрос загрузки аудио файла вконтакте (vk api)? C#

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, post

Сначала делаю запрос для получения адреса сервера для загрузки

```
https://api.vk.com/method/docs.getUploadServer?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&type=audio_message&v=5.63
```

В ответ получаю

```
{
  "response":
             {
               "upload_url":"https://..."
             }
}
```

Из этой строки извлекаю только адрес ссылки.
Теперь возникла проблема загрузки аудио файла на сервер. Как бы я не пробовал отсылать, возвращалась пустая строка. В документации ВК написано:

```
Допустимые форматы: MP3. 
Ограничения: файл объемом не более 200 МБ. 
Поле POST-запроса: file.

Передача файла:
Передайте файл на адрес upload_url, полученный в предыдущем пункте, 
сформировав POST-запрос с полем file. Это поле должно содержать mp3-файл в 
формате multipart/form-data.
```

Возможно, я неправильно делаю запрос. Буду благодарен за пример кода на C# POST запроса загрузки аудио файла. 
Мой вариант кода:

```
string filePath = @"D:\Soft\Visual Studio\Projects\VK audio messages\VK audio messages\VK audio messages\l1.mp3";

byte[] audio = convert(filePath);
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(audio, 0, audio.Length), "file", "l1.mp3");
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadUrl, form);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
httpClient.Dispose();
string sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
MessageBox.Show(sd);
****


byte[] convert(string fullFilePath)
   {
       FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fullFilePath);
       byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
       fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
       fs.Close();
       return bytes;
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Каким образом вы пытаетесь сделать запрос?
В [документации VK](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files) написано:

> 2. Передача содержимого файлов на полученный адрес в формате multipart/form-data.

Соответственно, загружать ваш файл нужно подобающим образом.
В С# я не силён, вот первый попавшийся вариант из гугла, взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19983672/7519767):

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(imagebytearraystring, 0, imagebytearraystring.Length), "profile_pic", "hello1.jpg");
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("PostUrl", form);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
httpClient.Dispose();
string sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Именем поля должно быть `file`, а `url`, куда загружаем - полученный ранее `upload_url`.

Пробовали ли вы подобный способ? Поищите примеры загрузки файлов в `multipart/form-data` формате на C#.

Comment: Я попробовал ваш вариант, но ничего не изменилось. Не могли бы вы глянуть корректность моего кода?

Comment: @AlexanderVeselov не стоит дополнять свои вопросы, добавляя ответы. Ответы нужны чтобы, собственно, давать ответы на поставленные вопросы. Удалите свой ответ и отредактируйте свой вопрос, чтобы добавить нужную информацию в него. Насчёт кода: с языком C# я не знаком, а потому вряд ли смогу точно найти ошибки в вашем коде.

Comment: @Arthur для работы с `audio_message` голосовыми сообщениями - позволяет

Answer (score 2):

У меня получилось так (не тестил с аудио, сделал с doc)

```
  using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            var uploadServerUrl = string.Format("https://api.vk.com/method/docs.getMessagesUploadServer?type=doc&peer_id={0}&access_token={1}", user_id, 
                access_tokken).GetStringFromUrl();
            string url = JsonObject.Parse(uploadServerUrl).Get<JsonObject>("response").Get<string>("upload_url");
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PathToFile)), "file", "name.txt");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, form);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            httpClient.Dispose();
            string fileFromVKServer = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var saveFile = string.Format("https://api.vk.com/method/docs.save?file={0}&access_token={1}",
                JsonObject.Parse(fileFromVKServer).Get<string>("file")
                , access_token).GetStringFromUrl();         
        }
```